# Itextsharp not finding barcode font

Tags: c#, itext, barcode

I have tried in several ways to get a barcode to appear in my iText paragraphs.
Here is how I have tried instantiating the font object.

```
Font bc39 = FontFactory.GetFont("~/Bin/FREE3OF9.TTF", 30);
```

But in the resulting file nothing shows up that looks like Georgia or something in 30 point font.

I have also tried the barcode39 approach and when I run it it returns System.Bitmap.Drawing instead of my barcode:

```
Barcode39 whlsc = new Barcode39();
whlsc.Code = "123456";
System.Drawing.Image whlscBarCode = 
    whlsc.CreateDrawingImage(
        System.Drawing.Color.Black, 
        System.Drawing.Color.White
    );
```

Here is how I try to add the paragraph. Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is the only thing standing between me and a finished product.

```
Paragraph itemLine9 = new Paragraph(@"*" + whBarCode + "*", bc39);
p.Add(itemLine9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by adding it as a Chunk rather than a paragraph in Itext

```
p.Add(new Chunk(whlsc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));
```

Comment: Congratulations! That means you have a finished product. Time to consider licensing ;-)

Comment: Ha far from that!

Comment: OK, no problem, so you are using iTextSharp under the AGPL. Can you share the complete source code of your finally finished product with us?

Comment: Or were you just pullung our leg when you wrote *This is the only thing standing between me and a finished product*?

Comment: Sorry been in meetings... if you want the whole code I can.. quite a large chunk of code!

Answer (score 0):

I think you posted the same question before, and I think that question was already answered:

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode 3 of 9"));
Barcode39 code39 = new Barcode39();
code39.Code = "ITEXT IN ACTION";
document.Add(code39.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
```

It is hard to understand your surprise that `CreateDrawingImage` returns a `System.Bitmap.Drawing` image as is indicated in the method name.

If you want an iText object that can be added to a `Document` or another iText object that allows adding images, why aren't you using the `CreateImageWithBarcode()` method?  Are you the same person as the one who posted this question: [Insertion of Illegal Element C# Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164697/insertion-of-illegal-element-c-sharp-itextsharp)